# Ошибки с python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, termux

Ошибки с python-telegram-bot. Работаю через termux

Ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Verifybot/mainT.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters                         File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from . import filters                           File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/filters.py", line 114, in <module>
    from telegram import Chat as TGChat           ImportError: cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram' (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/__init__.py)
```

Версия python-telegram-bot: 20.5

Код:

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram import Chat
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, есть два варианта действий:

1. Обновить библиотеку **telegram bot** (`pip install --upgrade python-telegram-bot`)
2. Не помогло? Юзайте `pip uninstall telegram`. Просто у вас есть несколько файлов, к которым обращается python по запросу *telegram*. Один из них нам не нужен:)

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка модуль "telegram ext" не содержит атребут "Filtres". Ошибка: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Verifybot/mainT.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext' (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/python_telegram_bot-20.5-py3.11.egg/telegram/ext/__init__.py) ```

Comment: `from telegram.ext import filters` вместо `from telegram.ext import Filters`

Comment: Помог? Поставьте галочку и проголосуйте))